# Is there a way to "dynamically" load json files into my component based on a condition?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, code-splitting

Let's say I have a couple translation files like so:

```
import English from "./lang/compiled-en.json";
import Spanish from "./lang/compiled-es.json";
```

and so on for all the languages we plan to support. These are imported directly into the component they are used, and our app as a whole is split into chunks with webpack that may contain many components and thus, many strings.
It would be ideal to only be importing the languages.json file I need depending on the user's locale, and not import all of them while having to check the locale and using only one.
I tried a super naive stab at it here, but it certainly does it work:
Helper function existing in another directory:

```
export async function loadLocaleData(locale: string, path: string ) {
  switch (locale) {
    case "en-US":
      return await import(path + "/lang/en-compiled.json");
    case "pt-BR":
      return await import(path + "/lang/pt-br-compiled.json");
    default:
      return await import(path + "/lang/en-compiled/en.json");
  }
}
```

I was thinking that importing this helper function into my components that need translations would look in their own directory for the translation file. But even when I have that path hardcoded to specify exactly where the translation file is, I still get errors.
The above may be implemented into a component like so:

```
  const localeContext = useContext(LocaleContext);

  const messages = loadLocaleData(
    localeContext.locale,
    "packages/components/Preferences/Billing"
  );
```

And then I'd ideally pass just that message into my IntlProvider that wraps this individual component.
This definitely isn't working. Is there a way to make it work? I know what I want to do, I'm just not sure how possible it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic imports like you are trying, but you need to use absolute paths. Otherwise your bundler (Webpack) won't actually know where to find them.

Alternatively, store your language files in your `public/` directory and use the public path to it. Webpack won't touch those files *(besides `index.html`)* and might be your best option here.

Comment: hmm, interesting. I am trying to include the absolute path (for example, from my repository root, the path would be 'packages/components/Preferences/Billing/lang/pt-br-compiled.json', which is what the path variable + my extention come out to be. But, I am getting a webpack missing module error. By absolute path, are you meaning from my computer itself?

Comment: Maybe I worded it wrong: when I said absolute paths, I meant "full relative paths" relative to the module you're importing from. Relative but without concatenation. _After all, absolute paths would actually make it check your `node_modules/`, not your actual file system._ Webpack basically goes through your code, looks for imports and sees "can I know what this import is trying to import? Great, bundle it!", which fails when you're concatenating. You basically always want to use `import('...')`, although I _think_ it also supports `import(cond ? 'pathA' : 'pathB')`, but it's very limited.

Comment: Now, would that allow it to be re-useable? All my components should have the same pattern - a lang folder in their directory containing the compiled language files, all named the same. So by using this function in any other component that is in a different directory, it should still look in said directory's path?

Comment: The import is relative to the module the import is used/written in. E.g. module A imports module B and module B does `import('./c')`, it'll be relative to the directory module B is in, not C.

Comment: Correction: it'll be relative to the directory module B is in, not A.